# "jotted down" or "written down"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

How can I put forward a formal notification which implies the following 
"We have incorporated all the suggestions written down in the Tracker by our onsite coordinator" ?

Here to me "written down" seems too trivial to express the actual tone of the sentence ?

How could it be written instead which will sound more formal in a corporate tone ? Please help

Comment: How about **recorded**?

Comment: What have you looked up and found in the way of synonyms for *write down*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about **catalogued**? It sounds pretty formal.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably use "noted" in this context, both formal and sounds like it has been carefully considered.

Edit: Dictionary def: "to make particular mention of in a writing"

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). This is a good suggestion, but the OP and the other users of the website would benefit from an explanation of why would you use this word, a dictionary definition and/or a quote of example of usage with references. Could you please add at least one of those? Thanks!